# Identify which VBA line is currently executing for progress bar

Tags: vba, excel, progress-bar, userform

I've created a progress bar with a user form. Currently the form calculates the progress by a manual line of code doing the following. To give context this is a parent macro which runs multiple underlying macros based on userform input.

Progress feeds the userform bar width.

```
Dim step As Integer
Dim totalsteps As Integer

'code
Call macro1
steps = steps + 1
progress = step / totalsteps

'code
Call macro2
steps = steps + 1
progress = step / totalsteps
```

Etc.

The progress bar is calculated based on these rigid steps in the parent macro code. I want to have a more fluid progress bar which ideally calculates the number of lines of code the module has to execute (denominator) and has the currently executing line of code as the numerator.

All the examples I have seen use a loop or for function which cannot be done here. All other suggestions on how to achieve the same goal are also welcome.

Comment: How do you want to count number of lines to be executed? You are lost in the moment where the code doesn't follow linear line by line execution - loops, if-else, function calls etc.

Comment: I am imagining it will be based on the checkboxes selected in the userform and will calculated based on that criteria. Of course this will not work if there is no function which is a continually updated line number (being executed) or the ability to automatically count the number of code lines in a module this will not work.

Comment: This can't be done automatically; you have to obtain the number of steps upfront and maintain the numerator yourself. Let's say the process is all encapsulated in sub "X". Sub X could take a boolean parameter that, when True, would make X follow all business logic, but without actually doing anything; it would just compute the total number of logic steps, storing it in e.g. a module-level variable. Then, you'd call sub X again, but with this parameter set to False, so X would follow the same logical path but actually do its thing.

Comment: righto, that's why my google had yielded nothing. That is my current solution, maintaining the totalsteps variable manually. I will have to unfortunately settle for a slightly blockier approach to the progress bar.